# What is the is() function in python

Tags: python, opencv

I have Been using python for a few years at this point and have never seen the `is` keyword being used as a function in an if condition.
I came across this code. It works as intended but I have no idea what the is() does.

```
def face_ext(img):
    gray = frame
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=1.5, minNeighbors=5)

    if faces is():
        return None

    for(x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cropped_face = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]

    return cropped_face
```

when removing the `is()` the code produces the following error:

```
[INFO] Initializing face capture. Look the camera and wait ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\smoke\miniconda3\envs\skyhawk\Scripts\skyhawk-script.py", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('skyhawk', 'console_scripts', 'skyhawk')())
  File "c:\Users\smoke\miniconda3\envs\skyhawk\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 829, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\smoke\miniconda3\envs\skyhawk\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "c:\Users\smoke\miniconda3\envs\skyhawk\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "c:\Users\smoke\miniconda3\envs\skyhawk\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "c:\Users\smoke\miniconda3\envs\skyhawk\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "c:\Users\smoke\miniconda3\envs\skyhawk\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\smoke\miniconda3\envs\skyhawk\lib\site-packages\click\decorators.py", line 21, in new_func    
    return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\smoke\documents\dev\python\skyhawk-cli\skyhawk\commands\cmd_capture.py", line 21, in color    
    result = capture.Capture.color()
  File "c:\users\smoke\documents\dev\python\skyhawk-cli\skyhawk\services\capture.py", line 41, in color        
    if face_ext(frame) is not None:
  File "c:\users\smoke\documents\dev\python\skyhawk-cli\skyhawk\services\capture.py", line 31, in face_ext     
    if faces:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()        
[ WARN:0] terminating async callback
```

the entire code file is given here at this [link](https://gist.github.com/devqueue/41288b9579881f94b70eb37f08c2318d).

Comment: As `faces` seems to be a numpy array, the best way to check if it is empty or not would probably be `if faces.size == 0:`. Also, there is no point in looping through the array only to return the last rectangle found. You can just do `x, y, w, h = faces[-1]; return img[y:y+h, x:x+w]`

Answer (score 6):

It's not a function at all, it's [the identity comparison operator](https://docs.python.org/3.9/reference/expressions.html#is-not).

> The operators `is` and `is not` test for an object’s identity: `x is y` is true if and only if x and y are the same object.

The statement

```
if faces is():
```

should be formatted as

```
if faces is ():
```

i.e. "is `faces` exactly this empty tuple object by identity?".

(Which it possibly never will be; the comparison should be `if faces == ():`, or maybe simply `if not faces:`).

Comment: `if not faces` is likely to raise an error similar to the one in the OP, as `faces` is an array and its truth value is ambiguous.

Comment: True. `if len(faces) == 0` might be safest.

Answer (score 0):

The Equality operator `(==)` compares the values of both the operands and checks for value equality.
Whereas the `‘is’` operator checks whether both the operands refer to the same object or not (present in the same memory location).

Answer (score 0):

Exactly as explained by others you are comparing the `__id__` of `faces` to the `__id__` of an empty `tuple`. That said you can use `faces.size` as your truth test and your code can be simplified a bit as well:

```
def face_ext(img):
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(frame, scaleFactor=1.5, minNeighbors=5)

    if faces.size: 
        x, y, w, h = faces[-1]
        return img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    else:
        return None
```